# Menu bar is not appearing

Tags: java, swing

The following code does not show any menu bar or menu in it.

```
notepad() //constructer
    {
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        ja =new JTextArea(10,20);
        jb = new JMenuBar();
        jm1 = new JMenu("File");
        jmi = new JMenuItem("one");
        setJMenuBar(jb);
        jb.add(jm1);
        jm1.add(jmi); 
        jf.add(jb); 
        jf.add(ja); //text area added
        jf.setVisible(true); // frame set true
    }
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that your class is extending from `JFrame`, remove that, it will then give you a compiler error on `setJMenuBar(jb);`, because `Object` doesn't have a method called `setJMenuBar`, instead you'll have to use the instance of `JFrame` you've already created...

```
jf.setJMenuBar(jb);
```

Also, you may consider using `JFrame#pack` instead of `JFrame#setSize`, but call it just before you call `setVisible`, otherwise you'll be packing nothing ;)